# Proof of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k{n \choose k}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}}=\frac{1}{n+2}$

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, combinations

> Deduce that
>   $$
> {n \choose 0}\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}-{n \choose 1}\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+{n \choose 2}\frac{1}{3\cdot4}+\cdots+{n \choose n}\frac{1}{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)}=\frac{1}{n+2}
> $$

Is induction a viable method to solve this problem? Or is there some other method which might be simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\left(x^{k}-x^{k+1}\right)\,dx $$
where the RHS is just
$$ \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{n+1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^{n+1}\,dx = \frac{1}{n+2}. $$

Comment: Was that a conversion from a Riemann sum in the second and third expressions? Or was it simple application of binomial theorem?

Comment: @Astrobleme: binomial theorem together with $\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}=\int_{0}^{1} x^k-x^{k+1}\,dx$.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that the sum is

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n+2\choose k+2} (-1)^{k+2}$$

which is

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\sum_{k=2}^{n+2} {n+2\choose k} (-1)^{k}
\\ = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\left(-{n+2\choose 0} (-1)^0 - {n+2\choose 1} (-1)^1\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\left(-1 + n+2\right) = \frac{1}{n+2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I don't quite understand, did you see my answer? It used the method. BTW on a different topic, do you happen to know how Brian Scott is doing? He has not posted since March.

Comment: I don't see a comment of yours on the page that you link to above. Can you maybe post the link here?

Comment: Well there is a link to my answer right below the question statement.

Comment: Oh, yes! I see! :-) Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.